# pythone web project in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7

I am new in python. I searched the web a lot to find a way to create pythone web project. The only thing that I got was to use google app engine. I use eclipse I created google app engine project with eclipse and now I do not know how to create html or something like servlet and so on I need a good source to start and get rid of this confusion can anyone introduce ay good source for python programming prefereably with eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 1):

you probably look for a [python web framework](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks), the default would be [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), see [review on django book vs django tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990944/review-on-django-book-vs-django-tutorial) for good starting point, download [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) and use it's PyDev perspective to start a new django project, see this [blog post](http://blog.yawd.eu/2011/using-aptana-studio-3-ide-django-applications-simp/) for starting with PyDev and django.

Good luck :)